# ANTLR4 Logical Expressions

Tags: java, expression, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I'm new to ANTLR and trying to support logical expressions. My problem is that the grammar is considering even a single '&' to be a logical AND (same goes for | and OR), which should not be the case.

Here's my grammar file (TagQuery.g4):

```
query
    : (expression)+
    ;

expression
    : keyValue                                                #comparisonExpression
    | inExpression                                            #singleInExpression
    | hasExpression                                           #singleHasExpression
    | expressionGroup                                         #singleExpressionGroup
    | expression logicalOperator expression                   #logicalExpression
    | expressionGroup logicalOperator expressionGroup         #expressionGroupExpression
    ;

inExpression
    : key IN literalList
    ;

hasExpression
    : HAS key
    ;

expressionGroup
    : NOT? L_RND_BRACKET (expression)+ R_RND_BRACKET
    ;


keyValue
    : key comparisonOperator literal
    ;

key
    :  KEY_PREFIX (keyName) R_RND_BRACKET
    ;

keyName
    : IDENTIFIER
    ;


comparisonOperator
    : EQ | NEQ
    ;

logicalOperator
    : AND | OR
    ;

literalList
    : L_SQ_BRACKET literal (COMMA literal)* R_SQ_BRACKET
    ;

literal
    : STRING_LITERAL
    ;


// keywords
AND                 : ' '*('&&' | 'AND' | 'and')' '*;
OR                  :  ' '*('||' | 'OR' | 'or')' '*;
IDENTIFIER          : [A-Za-z0-9_]+ ;
ESCAPED_IDENTIFIER  : '"' ( '"' '"' | [^"] )* '"';
STRING_LITERAL      : '\'' [A-Za-z0-9_ ]* '\'';
NOT                 : ' '*('!' | 'not' | 'NOT')' '*;
HAS                 : ' '*('HAS' | 'has')' '*;
IN                  : ' '*('IN' | 'in')' '*;
EQ                  : ' '*'='' '*;
NEQ                 : ' '*'!='' '*;
L_SQ_BRACKET        : ' '*'['' '*;
R_SQ_BRACKET        : ' '*']'' '*;
L_RND_BRACKET       : ' '*'('' '*;
R_RND_BRACKET       : ' '*')'' '*;
COMMA               : ' '*','' '*;
KEY_PREFIX          : 'tags('' '*;
//KEY_SUFFIX          : ')'' '*;
SPACE               : [ \t\r\n]+    -> channel(HIDDEN);
WS                  : [ \t\r\n]+    -> channel(HIDDEN);
//BLANK               : ' '*;
```

A sample valid query would be as follows:
`tags(environment) = 'prod' && tags(region) = 'syd'`

Here's the method that evaluates the query:

```
public static Filter forQuery(String query) throws ParseException {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Attempting to get tag filter for query {}", query);
            CharStream in = CharStreams.fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(query.getBytes()));
            TagQueryLexer lexer = new TagQueryLexer(in);
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            TagQueryParser parser = new TagQueryParser(tokens);
            TagQueryListener listener = new TagQueryListener();
            parser.addParseListener(listener);
            TagQueryParseErrorListener errorListener = new TagQueryParseErrorListener();
            parser.addErrorListener(errorListener);
            parser.query();
            if (errorListener.getException() != null) {
                listener.getFilter().setParseError(errorListener.getException());
                LOGGER.error("Tag filter for query {} returned an error. Please check query syntax \n {}", query, errorListener.getException());
                throw errorListener.getException();
            }
            LOGGER.info("Tag filter for query {} returned successfully", query);
            return listener.getFilter();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unexpected error encountered while getting filter for query {} \n {}", query, e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Here are some invalid queries:

```
(tags(project) = 'cloudcollectors' & tags(jira) = 'XTNXBL')
(tags(project) = 'cloudcollectors' | tags(jira) = 'XTNXBL')
(tags(project) = 'cloudcollectors'  tags(jira) = 'XTNXBL')
(tags(project) = 'cloudcollectors' tags(jira) = 'XTNXBL')
(tags(project) = 'cloudcollectors'tags(jira) = 'XTNXBL')
```

I expect the errorListener in the method above to throw an exception as these queries are syntactically incorrect. However, that does not happen and they proceed to return a Filter object.

Can someone suggest how to get past this? Am I missing something in my grammar? Thank you!

Comment: @BartKiers I'd really appreciate your expertise. Thanks!

Comment: How are `TagQueryParseErrorListener` and `getException` defined?

Comment: The error listener implements ```ANTLRErrorListener``` and has callback methods for syntax errors & ambiguities. The exception is initialized in these methods and returned via getException.

Comment: You have a "token recognition error"; the lexer rules are the problem. You don't define a token for '|', only for '||'. At that, you surround every token with optional spaces, which is highly unorthodox and unnatural. Further, the spacing around string literals, '*'-closure, parentheses, and symbols makes the rule difficult to read! If you have to recognize spaces around the literal, instead of `AND : ' '*('&&' | 'AND' | 'and')' '*;`, write something like `AND : Whitespaces ('&&' | 'AND' | 'and') Whitespaces; fragment Whitespaces: [ \t]*;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kaby76 points out, you're getting a token recognition error, this comes from the Lexer.  You'll also need to attach your `ErrorListener` to the Lexer.

```
lexer.addErrorListener(errorListener);
```

Also, you really want your ErrorListener to collect all of the errors it encounters.  Just interrogating `errorListener.getException()` is (probably) just going to give you the last error it encountered.

When ANTLR encounters a syntaxError, it's just going to can the `syntaxError(...)` method on all attached listeners and continue processing.  It's up to you to decide how to react to a syntax error reported to your listener.

You can choose how to handle your exceptions, but a "normal" process would be to build an `ArrayList` of all the errors you encounter and make it accessible in your `TagQueryListener` class.  Then you can add methods to check for errors, check max severity, check error count, etc.  (You could also just chose to throw an Exception to abort processing at the first error your encounter, but that's not going to be a great user experience.)

(I agree with his advise re: whitespace handling as well)

Comment: Thank you! Adding the error listener to the lexer helped.